# PHP inserting empty row in mysql table when file upload is empty

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a form, except file upload, i kept validations to other input types, but if i wont select any file, then my script is adding an empty in uploads table.Is there any way to check whether the user is uploading any file and if there is a file then i can run my upload script... here is the script

```
if (isset($_FILES['fileupload'])) {
    $errors     = array();
    $connection = db::factory('mysql');
    $user_id    = $_SESSION['userid'];
    foreach ($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['fileupload']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['fileupload']['type'][$key];
        if ($file_size > 2097152) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $upload_dir  = ROOT;
        $desired_dir = ROOT . "/uploads/";
        if (empty($errors) == true) {
            if (is_dir(ROOT . "/uploads/") == false) {
                mkdir(ROOT . "/uploads/", 0700);
            }
            if (is_dir(ROOT . "/uploads/" . $file_name) == false && !file_exists(ROOT . "/uploads/" . $file_name)) {
                $file_path = ROOT . "/uploads/" . $file_name;
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_path);
                $full_path = mysql_real_escape_string($file_path);
                $query     = "INSERT INTO uploads (`User_Id`,`File_Name`,`File_Path`,`File_Size`,`File_Type`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$full_path','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
                mysql_query($query);
            } else {
                $new_path = ROOT . "/uploads/" . time() . "_" . $file_name;
                rename($file_tmp, $new_path);
                $file_path = $new_path;
                $full_path = mysql_real_escape_string($file_path);
                $query     = "INSERT INTO uploads (`User_Id`,`File_Name`,`File_Path`,`File_Size`,`File_Type`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$full_path','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
                mysql_query($query);

            }
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if (empty($error)) {
        //echo "Success"; exit;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```

Comment: Your indentation scheme makes it really really hard to read your code. Consider using a text editor or an IDE that does it automatically for you.

Comment: .. Checking if the variables are empty? And **NOT** using deprecated libraries.

Comment: I didnt get u @Chris...

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the file upload field will create an entry in $_FILES whether it is empty or not. With that being the case, you're best to check either that `$_FILES['fileupload']['size'][$key]` is greater than zero OR that `$_FILES['fileupload']['name'][$key]` is not empty.

That should give you an answer for each file upload you have on your form (even if you have many.)

Comment: There's also `$_FILES['fileupload']['error']`, which will indicate if there was no file uploaded (or if some other error occurred).

Answer (score 0):

inside your `foreach loop`,
put the condition

```
if($_FILES['fileupload']['name'][$key]!="")
{
  //your code
}
```